# Use file/folder permissions of parent folder

Tags: debian, permissions, file-permissions

I have a folder called `Container` with the permissions `770`. So that the owner and the owner group can execute, read and modify the folder.

But when the owner adds files or folders to `Container`, they get the permission `755`.

Which commands do I need, so that every file (also files in sub-folders) and folder (also sub-folders, sub-sub-folders, ...) get the permission `770`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chmod -R 770` command to manually set the correct permissions to an element and all its children recursively.

If you you want users to create files with specific rights automatically, check on the `umask` shell possibilities.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask